# Unable to update Label in prompt box

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, visual-studio-2010, user-interface

I am working on the following code:

```
private Label textLabel;

public void ShowDialog()
        {
            Form prompt = new Form();
            prompt.Width = 500;
            prompt.Height = 150;
            prompt.Text = caption;
            textLabel = new Label() { Left = 50, Top=20, Text="txt"};
            TextBox textBox = new TextBox() { Left = 50, Top=50, Width=400 };
            Button confirmation = new Button() { Text = "Ok", Left=350, Width=100, Top=70 };
            confirmation.Click += (sender, e) => { prompt.Close(); };
            prompt.Controls.Add(confirmation);
            prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel);
            prompt.Controls.Add(textBox);
            prompt.ShowDialog();
        }
```

I am calling the above method using another method and trying to update the `textLabel` field inside a loop like this

```
    public void doIt()
    {
       ShowDialog();

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
       {
         textLabel.TEXT = ""+i;

         Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
       }

    }
```

That is the way we do in Java, but in C# it I could not update the label text in this way. What is wrong here and why can't I update the text?

Comment: ShowDialog() is modal, so it blocks the code from running until the form is closed.  I would use a timer instead of the for...loop / sleep.

Comment: ...or BackgroundWorker, in adition, textLabel is inaccessible (out of the scope) in doIt method

Comment: @NikolaDavidovic: It is defined as a global variable

Comment: Now it is, it wasn't at the first place, nevertheless, I don't think it is a good approach

Comment: The best way to do this is to make a separate form class with needed controls that will update its textLabel using timer (as @LarsTech) specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this is how I would do it, it is not a complete solution but I hope it will point you in the right direction:

Make the `Prompt` class that will derive from the Form. Add the controls to it (I did it manually but you could use the designer). Add the `Timer` which will be triggered on each second and which will change the label's text. When the counter hits 10 stop the timer.

```
public partial class Prompt : Form
{
      Timer timer;
      Label textLabel;
      TextBox textBox;
      Button confirmation;
      int count = 0;
      public Prompt()
      {
           InitializeComponent();
           this.Load += Prompt_Load;
           this.Width = 500;
           this.Height = 150;
           textLabel = new Label() { Left = 50, Top = 20, Text = "txt" };
           textBox = new TextBox() { Left = 50, Top = 50, Width = 400 };
           confirmation = new Button() { Text = "Ok", Left = 350, Width = 100, Top = 70 };
           this.Controls.Add(confirmation);
           this.Controls.Add(textLabel);
           this.Controls.Add(textBox);
           timer = new Timer();
           timer.Interval = 1000;
           timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
      }

      void Prompt_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
           timer.Start();
      }

      void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
           this.textLabel.Text = " " + count.ToString();
           count++;
           if (count == 10)
               timer.Stop();
      }
}
```

In the `doIt` method, create the instance of your `Prompt` form, set its caption and call its `ShowDialog()` method.

```
public void doIt()
{
    Prompt p = new Prompt();
    p.Text = caption;
    p.ShowDialog();

}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I really appreciate your help. Thank you :)